# What plan level is required to use PayPal with Cognito Forms?

Tags: cognito-forms, paypal

I have a PayPal account and want to use it to collect payment with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).  Do I need a paid account, and if so, which one?

Comment: The question doesn't show any research effort. Please checkout [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You can [collect payment via PayPal](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/paypal-payment) in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) as long as you are on the [Team or Enterprise](https://www.cognitoforms.com/pricing) plans.  Cognito Forms only charges a low monthly subscription, and the only processing fees are those you pay to PayPal directly.

When using Cognito Forms with PayPal, you can manage all of your entries and payments directly through Cognito Forms, including point of sale charges and refunds, without having to go to PayPal at all.